# Batch command to create folder based on filename and move files/folders to created folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a folder from a filename, which this does:

`for %%i in (*.png) do mkdir "%%~ni"`

After folder creation I'd like move a folder into this new folder.

`move "other_folder" %%~ni`

Comment: Well, then go for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your now completely changed question:

If there was only one `.png` file in the working directory, then you could simply do it in one line at the Command Prompt:

```bat
For %A In ("*.png") Do RoboCopy "other_folder" "%~nA" /E /MOVE >Nul
```

However, if you think about it, once the `other_folder` has been moved the first time, it is no longer there to be moved again! You would therefore need to instead copy it, then after all `.png` files have been processed, remove `other_folder`.

At the Command Prompt: *(two different commands, the first copies, the second removes)*

```bat
For %A In ("*.png") Do RoboCopy "other_folder" "%~nA" /E > Nul
RD /S /Q "other_folder"
```

Similarly from a batch file:

```bat
@For %%A In ("*.png") Do @RoboCopy "other_folder" "%%~nA" /E > Nul
@RD /S /Q "other_folder"
```

*Just take account that if anything goes wrong, (e.g. all of the content of `other_folder` doesn't copy), and you remove `other_folder`, you've lost that content.*

Comment: Thanks for this, it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

just extend the part to be executed by `DO`:

```
for %%i in (*.png) do (
  mkdir "%%~ni"
  convert "%%i" --folder="%%ni\test.bmp"
)
```

(not sure, how your `convert` command works - above is a guess)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your title request, the bellow script will create a folder named after each `*.png` in the directory then move the matching file into the newly created file.

**Batch:**

```
for %%i in (*.png) do (mkdir "%%~ni" && move %%i %%~ni)
```

**Command Prompt:**

```
for %i in (*.png) do (mkdir "%~ni" && move %i %~ni)
```

Comment: I want to move a different folder into the folder created by `"%~ni"`

Comment: Simply change the `%%i` to your folder name/source directory. ex: `move "source dir" "%%~ni"`

Comment: Please see my answer, John for a reason why the above comment should only work if there is only one .png file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody I was able to figure it out

`for %%i in (*.png) do mkdir "%%~ni" && move "folder" "%%~ni"`

Comment: Please see my answer for a reason why this should only work if there is only one `.png` file in the current directory.